# CodeMirror No Arrow Key Input on iPad using Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, codemirror

We are currently building a mobile game using AngularJS and CodeMirror that allows other developers to write javascript code to solve basic puzzles. Development has progressed quickly save one somewhat serious issue - it seems CodeMirror does not support the use of a bluetooth keyboard's arrow keys on iPad.

As an example of the problem you can simply navigate to codemirror.net on an iPad paired with a bluetooth keyboard and try to use the arrow keys in the example they provide on the homepage. No dice.

It appears this is a [known issue](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/issues/60) by [multiple accounts](https://github.com/marijnh/CodeMirror/issues/363) and no resolution seems forthcoming. While I'm aware of alternatives to CodeMirror I was really hoping someone out there in the SO community has seen and solved this problem. UI.CodeMirror (the angular module for CodeMirror) is really nice and except for this one problem everything else works great.

Does anyone have any work arounds? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not surprisingly CodeMirror's cursor position handling is based on javascript keypress events.  It should be easy for you to confirm that Mobile Safari does not generate keypress events for arrow keys (and hence no keycodes, and no cursor movements), either when using a wireless keyboard attached to a physical iPad, or when using a traditional keyboard and the iOS Simulator.  Probably the best solution would be to ask Apple to add arrow key event support to Mobile Safari, for situations such as these where people would like to use bluetooth keyboards for mobile access to CodeMirror-dependent applications.